# How to disable and enable the payements Methods on Wordpress (SEPA Stripe)?

Tags: wordpress, stripe-payments

I m working on E-commerce website which have many products using SEPA Stripe as Payement Method and orther Credit Card , my question is how to disable SEPA Stripe to some products and able SEPA Stripe to other products ?

Comment: It's a little hard to answer this as it's vague. _How_ do you accept payments? Are you using Checkout, or PaymentIntents directly, or something else? Can you share some of the code you use?

Comment: @karllekko i use Stripe Woocommerce as plugin to add payements methods like Credit Card and SEPA Stripe but when i active those methods it will be actived it for all the products